# Invoke-Sqlcmd2 do not terminate on error

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

Is there any way to make the function [`Invoke-Sqlcmd2`](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1) not terminate the rest of the script on failure?

I want the rest of my script to continue to run even if this command fails.

I've dug around the code and my thought is it has something to do with the `-ErrorAction` parameter.

Below is line 488 of the script:

```bsh
Catch # For other exception
{
    Write-Verbose "Capture Other Error"  

    $Err = $_

    if ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose) {Write-Verbose "Other Error:  $Err"} 

    switch ($ErrorActionPreference.tostring())
    {
        {'SilentlyContinue','Ignore' -contains $_} {}
        'Stop' {     Throw $Err} # Removing this line doesn't work
        'Continue' { Throw $Err}
        Default {    Throw $Err}
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this command to 'non-terminate'?

**Solution:**
Thanks for the info. I ended up wrapping the error handling section of invoke-sqlcmd2 in a try-catch trap.

Comment: The Catch {} is to handle exceptions thrown by the code. If you comment the switch Statement out, or the whole code, it should work. It stops on Stop, Continue AND the Default Action.

Comment: Or better, eliminate the error stated in $Err. What does it say?

Comment: Thanks Martin. This info helped with the above solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the Invoke-SQLCMD2 inside a try catch block and maybe log the error thrown.
That way you will handle the error and the script will go on.